# Binding NSPredicateEditor to Shared User Defaults Controller

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsuserdefaults, nspredicateeditor

I have an NSPredicateEditor that is part of a preference panel for a tool that I am making.

I would like to store the user's selections just as I would any other item in the NSUserDefaults object, but when I add the Binding to the NSPredicateEditor object and run the tool, it will not keep data and further it causes the other defaults to not show.  When I take away the binding and recompile, everything else comes back.

What is the best way to store the NSPredicatedEditor data as a user preference?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever the UI of an `NSPredicateEditor` changes, those changes are immediately reflected in the editor's `objectValue` (ie, its represented `NSPredicate`).  So you can just grab that predicate and archive it using an `NSKeyedArchiver`.  This will effectively turn the predicate into an `NSData` object, which can be saved out to `NSUserDefaults`.

To read it back in, just grab the `NSData` object, run it through an `NSKeyedUnarchiver`, and `setObjectValue:` on your predicate editor.

You can *probably* accomplish this through bindings, though I have never tried it.  [You can bind the `value` of an `NSPredicateEditor`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/BindingsText/NSPredicateEditor.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/NSPredicateEditor-DontLinkElementID_428) to something that supplies an `NSPredicate` (or an `NSPredicate` in `NSData` form).  You'll also probably need to specify that the value transformer is the `NSKeyedUnarchiveFromData` transformer.

Comment: Thank you.  It worked in Interface Builder using NSKeyedUnarchiveFromData.  This just saved me so much time.  I was implementing a delegate that would update the preferences with a description of the predicate on a button click.  But now thanks to your simple answer, I just hooked up the binding in the interface builder and it just works.  Great!